# SQL should I use a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help on a course question for my school. So I am supposed to get two tables `Seller` & `Item`, and I need to return the most active seller based on the most items offered. I have the tables as links below.

[image: Item Table]

[image: Seller Table]

How could I just return one record with the sellers `ID#` and `Name`? Do I need to do a subquery? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This seems like a complex question. I don't think a subquery is likely to be the intended approach though.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is a way to accomplish it via subquery. I don't know that any teacher would anticipate students using `>= all` though:

```
select s.sellerid, min(s.name) as name
from seller s inner join item i on i.sellerid = s.sellerid
group by s.sellerid
having count(*) >= all (
    select count(*)
    from item
    group by sellerid
)
```

You can also do it doubly=nested without even needing aliases!

```
select * from seller where sellerid in
(
    select sellerid from item group by sellerid
    having count(*) >= all (select count(*) from item group by sellerid)
)
```

Comment: I'm sure a lot of teachers these days anticipate their students posting homework questions on StackOverflow :)

Comment: How would I check that the item was sold? I tried to add an AND clause but it wont let me see below:  select * from SELLER where SELLERID AND ITEMSTATUS = 1 in
(
    select sellerid from item group by sellerid
    having count(*) >= all (select count(*) from item group by sellerid)
) Error : ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 37

Comment: Well that's bad syntax. But I think you wanted it in the innermost query anyway. There is no `itemstatus` in the images though.

Comment: @shawnt00 How would you implement it. I altered the table to have an item status field. In my next question, I need to find out who sold the most items.

Comment: Add `where itemstatus = 1` in the innermost query. It clearly has to be the one referencing `Item` ;)